# Errors for SQL Server connection in asp server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, executequery, executescalar, executereader

In an asp server we are getting error for SQL Server after executing `ExecuteScalar`, `ExecuteReader` and `ExecuteNonQuery` like shown below. The error will only come sometimes, it's not seen always. So anyone know why does this error comes? How to solve it?

> *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has occurred when sending    the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)*
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WriteSni()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WritePacket(Byte flushMode)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ExecuteFlush()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteSQLBatch(String text, Int32 timeout, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
>   at WinMsg.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: please make sure you have valid connection string. and access permission.

Comment: @Ravi He says they get that error after successful calls to the database.  I can't imagine they are changing the connection strings and access permissions all willy-nilly like that.

Comment: connection string is proper because the error come only few times.

Comment: I think it may be the error in your code of calling to the database. cn you pls update ur code connect with database?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned a `DataReader`: please ensure that you closed it correctly. I suspect it is still open and prevent further database operations.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326246%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> While the SqlDataReader is in use, the associated SqlConnection is busy serving the SqlDataReader. While in this state, no other
>   operations can be performed on the SqlConnection other than closing
>   it. This is the case until you call the SqlDataReader.Close method. If
>   the SqlDataReader is created with CommandBehavior set to
>   CloseConnection, closing the SqlDataReader closes the connection
>   automatically.

Also please ensure that `SqlConnection` object are closed and disposed properly after use.